# SQL Table Comparison Using CASE T SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, comparison, case-when

I am attempting to write a table comparison query that returns a Pass/Fail column when all of the values within a row are not equal. I have the basic syntax down, but it is Passing/Failing the entire data set, not the specific rows. Not sure if I need to use a sub query somewhere. Thanks!

```
Actual Output:
TestID    LastName    FirstName    PrimaryLevel Result
1         Smith       John         1            Fail
2         Jones       Adam         2            Fail
3         Barker      Bob          3            Fail

Expected Output:
TestID    LastName    FirstName    PrimaryLevel Result
1         Smith       John         1            Pass
2         Jones       Adam         2            Fail
3         Barker      Bob          3            Fail

--Code:
declare @TestID int

declare @TestIDExpected varchar(max)
declare @LastNameExpected varchar(max)
declare @FirstNameExpected varchar(max)
declare @PrimaryLevelExpected varchar(max)

declare @TestIDActual varchar(max)
declare @LastNameActual varchar(max)
declare @FirstNameActual varchar(max)
declare @PrimaryLevelActual varchar(max)

set @TestID = 3

set @TestIDExpected = (select TestID from ExpectedResults where TestID = @TestID)
set @LastNameExpected = (select LastName from ExpectedResults where TestID = @TestID)
set @FirstNameExpected = (select FirstName from ExpectedResults where TestID = @TestID)
set @PrimaryLevelExpected = (select PrimaryLevel from ExpectedResults where TestID = @TestID)

set @TestIDActual = (select TestID from ActualResults where TestID = @TestID)
set @LastNameActual = (select LastName from ActualResults where TestID = @TestID)
set @FirstNameActual = (select FirstName from ActualResults where TestID = @TestID)
set @PrimaryLevelActual = (select PrimaryLevel from ActualResults where TestID = @TestID)

select TestID, LastName, FirstName, PrimaryLevel, 
    case 
    when @TestIDExpected = @TestIDActual and @LastNameExpected = @LastNameActual and @FirstNameExpected = @FirstNameActual and @PrimaryLevelExpected = @PrimaryLevelActual  then 'Pass' 
    else 'Fail'
    END as Result from ActualResults
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit about your logic? Why is John Smith expected to pass and the other two fail?

Comment: No problem, thank you. John Smith will pass because all returned values in ExpectedResults and Actual results are =. The other two rows are not. Looking at it now, it may be something with TestID being set to 3, when I am attempting to run all 3 tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need can be achieved using plain SQL. Use a `LEFT JOIN` to always get the row back with a `TestResult` column filled with appropriate value indicating whether a match was found or not.

If you only have one row in both tables with `TestID = 3` then the result will return one row. You can modify the `WHERE` clause and your declared variable value to satisfy your needs.

Declaring variable with a value:

```
DECLARE @TestID INT = 3;
```

Running the comparison query:

```
SELECT
    a.TestID
  , a.LastName
  , a.FirstName
  , a.PrimaryLevel
  , CASE WHEN b.TestID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Pass' ELSE 'Fail END AS TestResult
FROM 
  ActualResults a
  LEFT JOIN ExpectedResults b ON
    a.TestID = b.TestID
    AND a.LastName = b.LastName
    AND a.FirstName = b.FirstName
    AND a.PrimaryLevel = b.PrimaryLevel
WHERE
  a.TestID = @TestID
```

If you'd like to compare entire dataset then you can drop the `DECLARE` statement along with a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT
    a.TestID
  , a.LastName
  , a.FirstName
  , a.PrimaryLevel
  , CASE WHEN b.TestID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Pass' ELSE 'Fail END AS TestResult
FROM 
  ActualResults a
  LEFT JOIN ExpectedResults b ON
    a.TestID = b.TestID
    AND a.LastName = b.LastName
    AND a.FirstName = b.FirstName
    AND a.PrimaryLevel = b.PrimaryLevel
```

Comment: This works, but only returns TestID of 3. If I wanted to return 3 rows of tests/data with TestID 1 and 2, would it be possible? Thanks

Comment: As I said in my answer, remove the `WHERE` condition. If you do that, you won't need the declared variable as well. It will scan entire `ActualResults` table.